# UWP Serial Port Access - Code Usually Doesn't Work

Tags: uwp, serial-port, gps

I am working with a standard NMEA GPS device. The serial port reads from the device and data is converted to a string that can be converted to Latitude and Longitude. This is the code I'm working with:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestReadAsync()
    {
        var aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM6");
        var deviceInformationCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
        var goodRead = false;
        uint maxReadCount = 1024;
        var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
        var deviceInfo = deviceInformationCollection.FirstOrDefault();

        Assert.IsNotNull(deviceInfo);

        using (var serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id))
        {
            serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            serialDevice.BaudRate = 4800;
            serialDevice.DataBits = 8;

            using (var dataReader = new DataReader(serialDevice.InputStream)
            {
                InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial,
                UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8
            })
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
                {
                    var dataReaderLoadOperation = dataReader.LoadAsync(maxReadCount);
                    using (var dataReaderLoadTask = dataReaderLoadOperation.AsTask(cancellationToken))
                    {

                        var readByteCount = await dataReaderLoadTask;
                        var buffer = new byte[readByteCount];
                        dataReader.ReadBytes(buffer);

                        var nmeaString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nmeaString))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(nmeaString);
                            goodRead = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(900);
                }
            }
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(goodRead);
    }
```

It worked once or twice. I.e. it read the data and I was able to see an NMEA string. But, most of the time `readByteCount` is 0.

I also tried this, and it seemed to work once or twice as well:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestReadAsync()
    {
        var aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM6");
        var deviceInformationCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
        var goodRead = false;
        uint maxReadCount = 1024;
        var deviceInfo = deviceInformationCollection.FirstOrDefault();

        Assert.IsNotNull(deviceInfo);
        using (var serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id))
        {
            serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            serialDevice.BaudRate = 4800;
            serialDevice.DataBits = 8;

            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                var emptyArray = new byte[maxReadCount];
                var emptyBuffer = emptyArray.AsBuffer();
                var buffer = await serialDevice.InputStream.ReadAsync(emptyBuffer, maxReadCount, InputStreamOptions.Partial);

                var data = buffer.ToArray();
                var nmeaString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nmeaString))
                {
                    goodRead = true;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Try: {i} {nmeaString}");
                    break;
                }
            }

            await Task.Delay(900);
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(goodRead);
    }
```

Here's one more version. `readCount` always gets 0;

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestReadAsync()
    {
        var aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM6");
        var deviceInformationCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
        var goodRead = false;
        var maxReadCount = 1024;
        var deviceInfo = deviceInformationCollection.FirstOrDefault();

        Assert.IsNotNull(deviceInfo);
        using (var serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id))
        {
            serialDevice.BaudRate = 4800;
            serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            serialDevice.DataBits = 8;

            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            using (var stream = serialDevice.InputStream.AsStreamForRead(0))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[maxReadCount];
                    var readCount = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, maxReadCount, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

                    if (readCount > 0)
                    {
                        var nmeaString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nmeaString))
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    Task.Delay(10);
                }
            }

        }

        Assert.IsTrue(goodRead);
    }
```

On .Net Core (Windows), with the same device, this code works consistently. I at least get an array of data from the serial port.

```
        using (var serialPortDevice = new WindowsSerialPortDevice(@"\\.\COM6"))
        {
            await serialPortDevice.InitializeAsync();
            var result = await serialPortDevice.ReadAsync();
            Assert.IsTrue(result.Data.Length > 0);
            var range = result.Data.ToList().GetRange(0, 10);
            Assert.IsFalse(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }.SequenceEqual(range));
        }
```

[Above Code](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/be795b38f713076a5234eb46054ae19f1314ede2/src/Device.Net.UnitTests/IntegrationTests.cs#L109)

Capabilities for good measure:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

*Note: I know the device is working because the app that comes with it is able to read the location, and I can see the stream of NMEA data there. I've also tried three different USB ports which end up being three different COM ports.*

**So, why is this so flaky? Is there are trick to getting serial port access to work on UWP consistently? Is there anyone out there with experience with reading from serial ports on UWP? Am I missing some code?**

Comment: I checked NMEA GPS devic uses a simple ASCII, serial communications protocol that defines how data are transmitted in a "sentence" from one "talker" to multiple "listeners" at a time.  But I found your code use `UTF8`.

Comment: I tried not specifying UTF8 but it makes no difference. This is only for string conversion though. The problem is that it is simply not reading any data at all.

Comment: You could add the breakpoints throughout the code and replicating again, does the issue occur within one of the Tasks being created? Such as `dataReader.LoadAsync(maxReadCount)` call. If we could inspect these calls while stepping through the code, it can potentially give us more information as to which particular call seems to be causing the issue.

Comment: In addition, it’s good to make sure that we are using the latest stable release of Visual Studio as that has some bug fixes that might help with this issue. Which windows build version is the UWP application targeting? This might help us further investigate if there are any new bugs within the framework as I understand that using a .Net Core app works fine.

Comment: Are there any error messages or warnings being logged within the console when debugging the UWP application? We are trying to see if this is an issue with the DataReader or something more to do with the SerialDevice class. Any additional information you would like to provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I've stepped through every line of this code. I posted the results of the first and third step-through process. I can see I missed the second one. I am using the latest stable version. I will need to get back to you about the other details.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have added the tests to the GitHub repo. You can clone the repo and see the problem for yourself. The branch is develop. The repo is: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net . The tests are here: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/4c4cadfc8b1cd3cef82d7e14648081ebb972123b/src/Device.Net.UWPUnitTests/SerialPortTests.cs#L18

Comment: Great, I will test your code.

Comment: Any GPS device would be good to test with

Comment: Currently, there is no GPS device in my side, So, I need report your issue to related team.

Comment: Try it a different serial port device then. It doesn't matter

Comment: Get It, If I receive any information, I will post below.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT any progress?